# My personal demese levies halved / improvements destroyed

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Hey my grand old king died at the age of 70 and I'm now playing my 7 year old heir. My personal levies have halved, for reasons unknown, even though I've kept the exact same demense.

Furthermore, many of the improvements I've built (e.g. I had level 3 jousting lists in my capital) have seemingly disappeared (now I'm back to square one).

Does anyone know why this could be? Any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I think this happened because your heir is not of the same culture as your previous character. Each culture have a [cultural building](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Cultural_buildings) only them can build, and a cultural retinue only them can hire. You where either a French or German culture before. If your current character is not in these groups, the retinues will disband and the buildings will be disable. Do not worry, they are still here, and will come back at the same level if you change culture.

To remedy this situation, be sure to have yourself educated by someone of the target culture. Since you are still rather young, they have a lot of time to convert you. If this fail, you'll just have to be more careful with your future children: take a wife (or husband) of the right culture, and educate them properly.

Comment: To give yourself the best odds of changing cultures back to match the old king, appoint a guardian who is of the desired culture who has Diligent, Gregarious or better yet, both. Either trait halves the Mean-Time-To-Hit and both quarters it, substantially increasing the odds of culture switch. Avoid Guardians who are Shy or Slothful as these traits produce the opposite effect.

Answer (score 2):

The amount of levies you can raise from your own personal holdings is partially scaled dependent on your martial stat. As you are a child, your martial stat likely isn't developed as high, so you can call on fewer personal troops.

The amount of levies raised from your vassals is dependent on their opinion of you (though there is a minimum amount dependent on crown law). As a new child ruler, your vassals like you less, since you are missing opinion bonuses due to long reign/short reign (probably around a 30 point swing from +20 to -10), lack of prestige (up to a maximum 20 point swing there), and state diplomacy (1/2 the total of your diplo stat which is likely lower + chancellor + 1/2 wife which you don't have). Thus you're likely only getting the crown law minimum.

Finally, the missing cultural buildings are explained by Jupotter - switching cultures destroys those buildings. To avoid, pay attention to the culture of your tutor.